# ngrok retrieve assigned subdomain

Tags: node.js, ngrok

I've got a NodeJS script which spins up a ngrok instance, which starts the ngrok binary.

However I'm needing to be able to return back the automatically generated url. I can't find anywhere in the documentation about how to do this.

for example, when you run `ngrok http 80` it spins up, generates you a random unique url each time it starts

[image]

Comment: Mean you want to get auto generated URL?

Comment: @abdulbarik i've included a little more info in the question :)

Answer (score 6):

This question is kinda old, however, I thought to give another more generic option as it doesn't require NodeJS

```
curl --silent --show-error http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels | sed -nE 's/.*public_url":"https:..([^"]*).*/\1/p'
```

This one just inspects the response of calling `api/tunnels` by applying text processing (`sed`) to the resulted text and identifies the public URL.

Answer (score 5):

ngrok serves tunnel information at `http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels`.

##### curl + jq

```bash
curl -Ss http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels | jq -r '.tunnels[0].public_url'

=> https://719c933a.ap.ngrok.io
```

##### curl + ruby

```bash
curl -Ss http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels | \
  ruby -e 'require "json"; puts JSON.parse(STDIN.read).dig("tunnels", 0, "public_url")'

=> https://719c933a.ap.ngrok.io
```

##### curl + node

```bash
json=$(curl -Ss http://127.0.0.1:4040/api/tunnels);
node -pe "var data = $json; data.tunnels[0].public_url"

=> https://719c933a.ap.ngrok.io
```